# How to fill an array with random numbers from 0 to 99 using the class Math?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I wrote the code, but there is no conversion from double to int.

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int[] ar1 = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i <  ar1.length; i++) {
            ar1[i] = int(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

How can it be corrected?

Comment: ar1[i] = ((int) Math.random() * 100);

Comment: A smart-enough IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ should be able to correct it by itself: `(int) (Math.random() * 100);`.

Comment: Not an answer, as you stated that you have to use Math, but the class Random has a nextInt()-funciton to create random integers

Comment: You're also declaring `i` twice, the first line in `main()` should be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be like

```
 ar1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

When you cast, cast type should be in brackets e.g. `(cast type)value`

Comment: You need to strictfp this.

Answer (score 7):

```
 ar1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

Conversion in Java looks like cast in C.

Comment: And is called casting as well.

Comment: You need to strictfp this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
package studing;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] ar1 = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
            ar1[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

1. Using `Math.random()` can return 1, this means `Math.random()*100` can return 100, but OP asked for maximum 99! Using `nextInt(100)` is exclusive 100, it can only return values from 0 to 99.
2. `Math.random()` can not return `-0.000001` that would be round to `0` **and** `1.0000001` can not be returned that should round to `1`. So you have less chance to get `0` or `99` than all the numbers between. This way it is not realy random, to guess "its not `0` or `99`" is more true than "its not `1` or `98`".
3. Also it do not make a detour via casting and mathematic operations you don't realy need, hey you dont need to `strictfp` on amd-cpus or old intel-cpus.

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually using the `java.lang.Math` class, but in Java 8 a random array can also be created in this fashion:

`int[] random = new Random().ints(100, 0, 100).toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses Random class instead of Math.random. Here it is.

```
private static int[] generateArray(int min, int max) {          // generate a random size array with random numbers
    Random rd = new Random();                                   // random class will be used
    int randomSize = min + rd.nextInt(max);                     // first decide the array size (randomly, of course)
    System.out.println("Random array size: " + randomSize);     
    int[] array = new int[randomSize];                          // create an array of that size
    for (int i = 0; i < randomSize; i++) {                      // iterate over the created array 
        array[i] = min + rd.nextInt(max);                       // fill the cells randomly
    }
    return array;
}
```