# How to make a "border" of 1s around matrix of 10 by 10 0s in a Java matrix (2d array)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, matrix

I am new to java, so, please respond with clear and direct answers. I made a 12 by 12 matrix of 0s.

```
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
000000000000
```

I want to surround the middle area with a "fence" of 1s.

```
111111111111
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
100000000001
111111111111
```

I am really new to Java so I only know how to make the 12 by 12 and print it, but now how to make the fence. I also want to know how I could randomly spawn in 10 random 1s inside of the 10 by 10 grid of 0s using a loop. Please help!!!! Here is my code:

```
class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args){
 int[][] gameboard = new int[12][12];// make gameboard
 int r_length = gameboard.length;//row length
 int c_length = gameboard[0].length;//column length
 for (int x = 0; x < gameboard.length; x++) {
   for(int y = 0; y < gameboard.length; y++){
     gameboard[x][y] = x + y;
     gameboard[0][y] = gameboard[1]; //replace row 1 (not working)
     gameboard[11][y] = gameboard[1]; //replace row 12 (not working)
     gameboard[x][0] = gameboard[1]; //replace column 1 (not working)
     gameboard[x][11] = gameboard[1]; //replace column 12 (not working)
    }
  }

 for (int[] a : gameboard) {
   for (int x :a) {
     System.out.print("0");
    }
   System.out.println();
  }//gameboard printing
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here:

1. Inner loop should iterate over inner length:

   ```
   for(int y = 0; y < gameboard[0].length; y++)
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   for(int y = 0; y < gameboard.length; y++)
   ```
2. You cannot assign array to `int`, types must match.

   ```
   gameboard[0][y] = gameboard[1];
   ```
3. This won't do what you want: `gameboard[x][y] = x + y;`. It assigns a sum of indices.

Since it's a square (both lengths equal), you can iterate once:

```
for (int x = 0; x < gameboard.length; x++) {
     gameboard[0][x] = 1;
     gameboard[11][x] = 1;
     gameboard[x][0] = 1;
     gameboard[x][11] = 1;
}
```

Before that you were doing the same work `gameboard.length` times.

You should also print it properly:

```
 for (int[] a : gameboard) {
   for (int x :a) {
     System.out.print(x);
    }
   System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: why is the y-axis position for x? (line 2 of last code)

Comment: the code didn't work. I just got a 12 by 12 of 0s. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: It's not x index, simply index in both dimensions

Comment: @UserX maybe you got 0s, because you're printing 0s only... Check out my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly different suggestion here: don't put the border **into** your data.

What if you want to have "*" tomorrow instead of those 1s?! Then you are broken, because you have an array of int, not of chars?!

Meaning: you should actually separate your *data* and the *printing format*.

Sure, that makes the printing more complicated (or not, see below), but your approach does have a lot of ugly consequences. For example: what if you want to pass that matrix to some "computation" code at some point? Then that computation code will have to know where/how your "border" sits in that data, to exclude it from its computation. Or when you decide to turn your "text console" program into a GUI application? Then you will probably really *draw* a border line ... but you will keep carrying around your matrix that includes those "border line" chars (pun intended).

Thus, why not go:

```
printTopLine();
for (int[] rows : gameboard) {
  printRow(row);
```

where

```
public void printTopLine() {
   ...println("1111...
}
```

and

```
public void printRow(int[] values) {
   print("1");
   for (int v : values) print(v);
   print("1");
}
```

As you can see: this is actually very straight forward, and whenever you decide: I want to print things in a different way, you just go in and change thing were necessary, without ever worrying about the data *within* your 2D array!

So, long story short: you could change your code so that your 2D matrix is **only** about the values of your game board, and how to "display" that is completely done by *other* code!

Comment: for clarification, you want me to make a 10 by 10 2d matrix, and then to follow your generous code to make a border to keep the border and matrix separate. Also, in your "where" code what are the ... for? Furthermore, how could I randomly generate 10 1s in the newly made 10 by 10 2d matrix?

Comment: @UserX As in: there are really plenty of questions around here, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768435/how-to-fill-an-array-with-random-numbers-from-0-to-99-using-the-class-math ... . Just put "java array random numbers" into your favorite search engine"

Comment: ghost cat, the error "return type required" what does that mean?

Comment: @UserX It means that you defined a method and missed a return type. When you look at my example, you see that it says "void". That means: wont return anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char border = '1';
    char fillCharaters = '0';
    int gridLength = 12;
    int gridWidth = 12;
    char[][] arr = new char[12][12];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int j=0; j<gridWidth ; j++){
        for (int i=0;i<gridLength;i++){
            if(j==0||j==gridWidth-1||i==0||i==gridLength-1){
                arr[j][i] = border;
            } else {
                arr[j][i] = fillCharaters;
            }
        }
        //To print the random characters in the 10X10 grid
        int r = random.nextInt(11);
        arr[j][r] = border;
    }
    print2DMatrix(arr);
}

public static void print2DMatrix(char mat[][]) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++){
            if(j==mat[i].length-1){
                System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
            } else{
                System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
            }
        }       
    }    
}
```